# JQM & Angular: Pass value from page to page

Tags: api, angularjs, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have been struggling with this for a day and can't seem to figure out the best way to get it working.

I am building a Phonegap, Jquery Mobile and Angular JS App. JQM for pages, AngularJS to pull in data from an API.

I have a UL list of pages that link to full descriptions. When clicked, I need to load another JQM page and pass a value to that pages controller to enable to query the API.

I have tried everything from local storage, ng-clicks a factory to share values. I can't seem to get the second controller to see the value passed. Anyone with an idea where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

## List-of-pages controller

This is the controller that loads the list view of page title

```
// Factory to get categories
app.factory("api_get_categories_by_group", function ($resource) {
return $resource(
    "http://MYDOMAIN.com/api/get_categories_by_group",
    {
        "group_id": "9"
    }
  );
});

// Get the list from the factory and put data into $scope.categories so it can be repeated
function categoryList ($scope, api_get_categories_by_group, getID) {
  $scope.categories = [];

  // Get all categories returned by the API
  $scope.categories = api_get_categories_by_group.query();

  $scope.getCatID = function (id) {
    getID.prepForBroadcast(id);
  };
}
```

## Factory to handle the sharing of data

This controller is based on: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/

```
app.factory("getID", function ($rootScope) {
var sharedID = {};
sharedID.theID = '';

sharedID.prepForBroadcast = function (id) {
    this.theID = id;
    this.broadcastItem();
};

sharedID.broadcastItem = function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
};

return sharedID;
});
```

## detail-page controller

This controller needs the shared value to enable query of API

```
// Factory to get products by category
app.factory("api_get_channel_entries_products", function ($resource) {
return $resource(
    "http://MYDOMAIN.com/feeds/app_productlist/:cat_id",
    {
        cat_id:'12'
    }
);
});

// Get the list from the factory and put data into $scope.categories so it can be repeated
function productList ($scope, api_get_channel_entries_products) {

$scope.products_list = [];

$scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
    $scope.catID = getID.sharedID;
    console.log($scope.catID);
});

$scope.products_list = api_get_channel_entries_products.query();
}
```

I've generally been experimenting with an mg-click to pass the id of a page through - HOWEVER, I've haven't added this to the code as I believe it is probable the root of the issue.

HTML: hg-click

```
<li ng-repeat="cat in categories"><a href="#product-list" ng-click="getCatID(cat.cat_id)">{{cat.cat_name}}</a></li>
```

Comment: Where are to trying to access the shared data. Can you highlight that part of code.

Comment: Oops. Sorry Chandermani - That would have made sense! Generally I have been playing with a hg-click and function. I've added to the Q. I haven't added that code as I am thinking it is the root of the issue here.

Comment: There is something fishy with `getCatID` method. Since you have used it in expression this would be caller number of time during each digest cycle and hence broadcast the message again and again.

Comment: Ahh, that is a good point. Thanks. Do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert, but I had similar problems when I wanted to pass data between controllers. The following approach worked best for me:

```
app.service('dataService', function() {

    var _currentData = {};

    return {
        getCurrentData: function(){
            return _currentData;
        },
        setCurrentData: function(input){
            _currentData = input;
        }
    };
});
```

In a controller that would need to access the data:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
        return dataService.getCurrentData();
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
            $scope.Data = newValue;
        }
}, true);
```